# Bug in Cocoa NSBitmapImageRep?

Tags: cocoa

I noticed that when creating a NSBitmapImageRep using initWithBitmapDataPlanes and providing an existing owned data buffer, then after calling drawInRect the NSBitmapImageRep object may have replaced the pixel data by its own version, and thus bitmapData returns another pointer than what i originally provided and then changing the pixels in my buffer won't have any effect anymore when redrawing the NSBitmapImageRep! This is clearly contrary to the documentation! I wanted to take advantage of the documented fact that when providing your own pixel data buffer it will be preserved, but it is not! Am i missing something? If not then i want to share this info here so that others don't have to waste a lot of time looking for a code bug while the issue is the NSBitmapImageRep class behaving different than documented.

Comment: I don't think they docs say what you think they say.  "The object treats the image data in the buffers as immutable and will not attempt to alter it."  It does not say that it will continue to use this image data after the `NSBitmapImageRep` has been created, and pay attention to changes in the image data.

Comment: The docs say "If planes is not NULL and the array contains at least one data pointer, the returned object will only reference the image data; it will not copy it." So yes it says that it will continue to use that data buffer, which it doesn't. So i think that's a bug in the implementation or in the docs.